# Settings a listener to Shared Preference's dialog 'OK' button

Tags: java, android

I have class Settings that extends PreferenceActivity,
in which user enter his Google account and the password. When the user presses 'add account' a dialog jumps with OK and CANCEL buttons.
Same occurs when pressing add password, I want to define listener within PreferenceActivity
to the OK button in the password dialog, that when the OK button is pressed the listener automatically checks if the user has entered the password correctly.

Comment: "I have class Settings that extends PreferenceActivity, in which user enter his Google account and the password." -- please don't. Users should not have to provide you with that information. If you are using this account to access Google services, there is a new Java library that integrates with Android's `AccountAuthenticator` and avoids the user having to provide the data.

Comment: I had a hunch, something is wrong with this way of thinking. Anyway can you give me more details about this library?

Comment: I can point you to it: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ There was also a conference session on it at Google I|O 2011, with a YouTube video.